# textbox keypress word count not working when past words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to allow only 300 words in a textbox. It is working fine, but when I paste it doesn't work. I need to trim 300 words after paste and not allow more than 300 words.

What needs to change in my code?

```
var max = 300;
var maxWords = "Words Max: 300";
$('#AbstractTextText').keypress(function (e) {
    var val = $.trim($('#AbstractTextText').val()), // Remove spaces from b/e of string
        words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length, // Count word-splits
        chars = val.length;

    if (words < max) {
        $('#spanWordCnt').text((max - words) + ' words remaining (' + maxWords + ').');
        // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
        // e.which === 0 - Not a character
        return;     // Do nothing
    }
    if (words == max) {
        $('#spanWordCnt').text((max - words) + ' words remaining (' + maxWords + ').');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (words > max) {
        alert(this.value.substring(0, chars));
        $('#spanWordCnt').text((max - words) + ' words remaining (' + maxWords + ').');
        // Maximum exceeded
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, chars);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('#AbstractTextText').on("input", function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

You could you the `on` event using `paste` :

```
var maxWords = 300;
$("#AbstractTextText").on("paste", function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var text = $("#AbstractTextText").val().split(" ");
        while (text.length > maxWords) {
            text.pop();
        }
        $("#AbstractTextText").val(text.join(" "));
    }, 0)
})
```

This will only word for the pasted content you will still need your keyup event.

Comment: it is still allowing me text to enter. it suppose to strips words tp 300.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point ? about allowing ... with this code you can catch paste event then the `text.pop();` is poping out extra word. Do you need extra validation ? or error message ? some kind of disabled field when you reach 300 ( this wont be useful for correction ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following three events together:

```
var maxAmountOfCharacters = 300;

$('texarea').on('change keyup paste', function(e) {
    ... // do things
});
```